# Converting numpy variables to tf variables for graph freezing purpose

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm having a problem converting the numpy variable to tf variable.
The original code I'm trying to change is as follows

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
training_set_inputs = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
training_set_outputs = array([[0, 1, 1, 0]]).T
random.seed(1)
synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1
for iteration in xrange(10000):
 output = 1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights))))
synaptic_weights += dot(training_set_inputs.T, (training_set_outputs - output) * output * (1 - output))
print 1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 0, 0]), synaptic_weights))))
```

I've edited some of the lines to be

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
import tensorflow as tf
import os
dir =os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('/Users/karnny/Desktop/Project'))


training_set_inputs = tf.Variable([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
training_set_inputs_transpose = tf.transpose(training_set_inputs)
training_set_outputs = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 1, 0]])
training_set_outputs_transpose = tf.transpose(training_set_outputs)
random.seed(1)

saver = tf.train.Saver() 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #adjust weight
    weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1

    #train neural network
    for iteration in range(10000):
        output = 1 / (1 + exp(-(tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights,1))))
    weights += tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs_transpose, (training_set_outputs_transpose - output) * output * (1 - output),1)

saver.save(sess, dir + '/data-all')
#test result
print (1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([0, 1, 0]), synaptic_weights)))))
print (1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 1, 0]), synaptic_weights)))))
print (1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 0, 1]), synaptic_weights)))))
print (1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([1, 0, 0]), synaptic_weights)))))
print (1 / (1 + exp(-(dot(array([0, 0, 0]), synaptic_weights)))))
```

There seems to be an error about the variable type on the 'output' variable. The error if as follows.

```
TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float64 that does not   match type int32 of argument 'a'.
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Update: 
This is my updated code.

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot
import numpy 
import tensorflow as tf
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('/Users/karnny/Desktop/Project'))



training_set_inputs = tf.Variable([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]], dtype = tf.float64 )
training_set_inputs_transpose = tf.transpose(training_set_inputs)
training_set_outputs = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 1, 0]])
training_set_outputs_transpose = tf.transpose(training_set_outputs)
random.seed(1)

saver = tf.train.Saver() 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #adjust weight
    synaptic_weights = tf.Variable(2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1, dtype = tf.float64)
    #tf.cast(synaptic_weights, int)
    #synaptic_weights.astype(numpy.int64)
    #training_set_inputs_float = float(training_set_inputs)
    k = tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights, [[1], [0]])

    #train neural network
    for iteration in range(10000):
        #output = 1 / (1 + tf.exp(-(tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights,[[1], [0]]))))

        output = tf.sigmoid(k)
        #tf.to_int32(output,name='ToInt32')
        tf.cast(training_set_inputs_transpose, tf.float64)
        tf.cast(training_set_outputs_transpose, tf.float64)
        tf.cast(output, tf.float64)
        #tf.to_int32(training_set_inputs_transpose,name='ToInt32')
        #tf.to_int32(training_set_outputs_transpose,name='ToInt32')
        #tf.to_float(weights,name='ToFloat')
        weights += tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs_transpose, (training_set_outputs_transpose - output) * output * (1 - output),[[1], [0]])

    saver.save(sess, dir + '/data-all')
```

The error occured with the 'weight' variable
The error is as follows

```
 Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float64: 'Tensor("Sigmoid_21:0", shape=(4, 1), dtype=float64)'
```

I'm pretty sure I've changed the variable types to float but the error still appears.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the code was originally from https://github.com/miloharper/simple-neural-network/blob/master/short_version.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily using the `numpy ndarray` with `tf tensor` simultaneously, you can define operations such as combine or add the two type of data.
But the error you got, is just because you need to understand that, when you try to do the `MatMul` operation in `tf`, the two input data `a` and `b` must has the same type, as you can see,

```
synaptic_weights = 2 * random.random((3, 1)) - 1
```

you can get a `weights` variable with type `np.float64`, because `np.random.random((,))` return a `float` type (you can run `synaptic_weights.dtype` to see the true type). But, you also write that,

```
output = 1 / (1 + exp(-(tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs, synaptic_weights,1))))
```

when you try to run the `tf.tensordot` operation, the input `a` is `training_set_inputs` with a type of `int32_ref` or `int32`, but input `b` is `synaptic_weights` with a type of `float64` as default, that's why you get the error.

**To solve this error**, you can define the tf variable with the `float` type at the beginning.

Comment: Wow, that helps. Many thanks. Can you help me further?
 weights += tf.tensordot(training_set_inputs_transpose, (training_set_outputs_transpose - output) * output * (1 - output),[[1], [0]])
This weight seems to require int variable. I tried to convert. by using
tf.to_int32(training_set_inputs_transpose,name='ToInt32')
        tf.to_int32(training_set_outputs_transpose,name='ToInt32')
        tf.to_int32(output,name='ToInt32')
but it didn't help, any idea?

Comment: @KarnPiriyapanya generally, we actually seldom use int32 to be the input or the weights, we prefer `float32` or `float64` dtype, if you still want to use int dtype, you can try `tf.cast`

Comment: I'm afraid so. Now, I tried to change back to float64 by using tf.cast(training_set_inputs_transpose, tf.float64)
        tf.cast(training_set_outputs_transpose, tf.float64)
        tf.cast(output, tf.float64)
but the error said 
Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float64
Is it possible that I haven't convert all the variables used in the 'weight'?
I have changed all of the training variables to float64 already, but somehow I got that error.